# Problems with C language code

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

> Write a complete program.
>
> - The program should read two integers: **m** and **n**, from the keyboard.
> - Allocate memory for a dynamic 2D **m** * **n** array of doubles.
> - Initialize the array according to the formula `A[i][j]=(i-5)/(j+1)`.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int m,n;
    scanf ("%d %d",&m &n);

    double**A=(double**) malloc (m*size of (double*));
    double*B=(double*) malloc (m*n * size of (double));

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        A[i]=B+i*m;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (int j=0;i<m;j++){
            A[i][j]=(i-5)/(j+1);
        }
    }
    free (A);
    free (B);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C# and C are two very different languages

Comment: oh excuse me i taged wrong

Comment: `problems with c language code` is a truly horrible title - it could apply to every c/c++/c# post on the site. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: i wanted to know only if my code is correct

Comment: @robertpeterfernandes: Did you try it and see?

Comment: yes but dint compile:( @MarkBenningfield

Comment: @robertpeterfernandes: Well, I suggest that you enable all warnings on your compiler and edit the code until you can get it to compile.

Comment: Next time add all relevant information in your question. Stack Overflow is not a platform meant to inspect random code dumps. Read the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Few things wrong:

- `size` not defined.
- `#include <math.h>` is not needed since you don't call any math functions.
- Strictly speaking you should `#include <stdlib.h>` as this declares `malloc()` and friends.
- A `,` is missing in `scanf ("%d %d",&m &n);`.
- No need to cast `malloc()` return value.
- Always start variable names with a small letter.
- You have one `}` too many.
- Indentation and code formatting is really bad and is asking for trouble.**
- ...

Check [this section of the C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html) to see if you've done the allocation correctly.

Idea: Read through the C-FAQ mentioned above, it will teach you a lot and will turn out to be a valuable time investment.

**Here's an example of good code indentation & formatting (without fixes):

```
int main()
{
    int m;
    int n;

    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    double** A = malloc(m * size of (double*));
    double*  B = malloc(m * n * size of (double));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        B[i] = B + i * m;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < m; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = (i - 5) / (j + 1);
        }
    }

    free(A);
    free(B);

    return 0;
}
```

Well, I fixed the superfluous `}`.